# what are the sequence 111 211 121 221 112 212 122 222?

Tags: sequences-and-series

while studying operations of multiple scenarios, I realized the following sequence of numbers;

$$
1\quad 2\\
11\quad 21\quad 12\quad 22\\
111\quad211\quad 121\quad 221\quad112 \quad212 \quad122\quad222\\
1111\quad2111\quad1211\quad2211\quad1121\quad2121\quad1221\quad2221\quad1112\quad2112\quad1212\quad2212\quad1122\quad2122\quad1222\quad222\\
$$

they get larger every step by 2 times the pervious sequence. Are there any know sequence that look like this?

Comment: The first row should be 1-2

Comment: @user376343 Yes its actually, i missed, i added it now, thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the $k$th entry ($1\le k\le n$) of the $n$th row: Write $k-1$ as an $n$-bit binary number, reverse it, increase each digit.

For example with $n=4$ and $k=5$: $$k-1=4\to 0100\to 0010\to 1121$$

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is that the length of each sequence is $2^n$.  This is because the sequences are generated by all combinations where I can either choose a $1$ or a $2$ in each position.  So, the sequence of elements each with length $4$ will have $2^4 = 16$ elements, which is what you show.  Verify for other sequences.

A pattern similar to what you have is called Gray Code, which will show all $2^n$ elements, but in a different ordering, where only one numeral is changed between successive terms.

Comment: This doesn't look Gray to me: $\ldots, 2111,1211,\ldots$